# SSD showing incorrect size

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I've just bought an OWC aura SSD upgrade For my MacBook Pro late 2013 retina and it should be 1TB but is only showing a size of 480gb. Is there anything I can do to get it to show the correct size, or is it a hardware fault?

Comment: What does `diskutil info disk0` give you?

Comment: Or, if you don't use the command line interface, what do you see in Disk Utility? Is it possible your 1 TB has been partitioned?

Comment: diskutil says this:

`Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Whole:                    Yes
   Part of Whole:            disk0
   Device / Media Name:      OWC Aura SSD

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 PCI
   SMART Status:             Verified`

Comment: and this

   `Disk Size:                480.1 GB (480103981056 Bytes) (exactly 937703088 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)

   Device Location:          External
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              Yes
   Virtual:                  No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported`

Comment: Please post that info into the **question** by *editing* it, not putting it in comments.  That said - you have a 480.1GB drive.  You need to contact OWC